# Parsing ajax JSON response in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

So I try to parse json response from ajax request with `JSON.response`, but it doesn't work

the example of the json response from my api looks like this :

```
{"cn":"3335621215844","status":5,"proxy":"207.154.231.213:8080","error":"Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT"}
```

here's the error from the broswer debug :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

here is my code :

```
function cn_doCheck() {
    var proxy_counter = 0;
    var cn_list = $("#cn_input").val().split('\n');
    var proxy_list = $("#proxy_input").val().split('\n');
    var i=0;
    if (cn_list!="" && proxy_list!="") {
        $.each(cn_list, function(index, value){
                if (i>proxy_list.length) {
                    i=0;
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'post',
                    data : {
                        cn: value,
                        proxy: proxy_list[i]
                    },
                    url : 'api_test.php',
                    async : true,
                    beforeSend: function(response){
                        $("#loader").empty();
                        $("#loader").append("Checking "+cn_list.length+" in total");
                    },
                    success: function(response){

                    },
                    complete: function(response){ 
                        var result = JSON.parse(response);                       
                        $("#cn_live").append(result.cn+"|"+value+"|"+proxy_list[i]+"\n");
                        i++;
                    }
                });
            });
    }else{
        alert("Card/Proxy list can't be empty!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a `console.log(response)` inside success & complete method to see what is actually returned?

Comment: @palaѕн here the return result from the resuest
responseText: "{"cn":"3335621215844","status":5,"proxy":"207.154.231.213:8080","error":"Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT"}"

Comment: I been try to parse the response with JSON.parse but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like *response* is already a JavaScript object not a string, you do not need to parse that again.

**Update:** Ajax `success()` only gets called if your web server responds with a 200 OK HTTP header - basically when everything is fine. Where as, `complete()` will always get called no matter if the ajax call was successful or not - maybe it outputted errors and returned an error - `complete()` will still get called.

Please execute your code inside `success` call back to avoid unwanted scenario.

Comment: the response is in json,when i try to append the response without json parsing it, it looks like this 
`[object Object]`

Comment: @NeiosFlameStuxnet, what `result.cn` shows in console?

Comment: @NeiosFlameStuxnet, what if `result.data.cn`?

Comment: it is error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cn' of undefined`

Comment: @NeiosFlameStuxnet, without seeing the problem live it is really difficult to find out the issue:)

Comment: @NeiosFlameStuxnet, one more thing, why don't you try the code inside `success` call back instead of `complete`...

Comment: ohh I see,it worked with JSON.parse when i move the code inside `success`, Thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**
It appears that the response is already in JSON format.

Parsing the response:

```
complete: function(response){ 
  var result = JSON.parse(response); 
  $("#cn_live").append(result.cn+"|"+value+"|"+proxy_list[i]+"\n");
  i++;
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "cn": "3335621215844",
  "status": 5,
  "proxy": "207.154.231.213:8080",
  "error": "Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT"
}
```

If you try to use `JSON.parse` with an object that is already in JSON format, it will give you the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

---

**Solution**

So I think you do this instead:

```
var result = response
```

Comment: so how do i get the specific object ? for example I want to get the `status` from the reponse

Comment: I try `result.status` but it returned `undefined`